# IPsec on pfSense: Tunnel is up, but I can't connect to remote host

Tags: networking, vpn, pfsense, ipsec

I have a strange problem with my IPsec VPN:
I have 2 matched [hardware and software - 2.4.4 release p3] pfSense boxes at different locations.
Each pfSense is a Firewall + DHCP server + Gateway for the local LAN.
I have setup an IPsec tunnel between the two gateways, but while I can access both gateways from a local host, I can't connect to any remote hosts.

Additionally the local gateway can't ping the remote gateway.

- Local host pings local gateway
- Local host pings remote gateway
- Local host cannot ping remote host
- Local gateway cannot ping remote gateway

Local subnet: 192.168.10.0/24

Remote subnet: 192.168.9.0/24

Sitting at either location, I can access both gateways, but nothing else on the remote side.

Both gateways have the P1 and P2 settings exactly the same [apart from switching local and remote networks / gateways on the respective boxes]

Here are the P1 settings:

- Key Exchange Version: IKEv2
- Internet Protocol: Both (Dual Stack)
- Interface: WAN [which is on a static IP]
- Remote Gateway: Static Ip of remote Gateway

P2 Settings:

- Mode: Tunnel IPv4
- Local Network: 192.168.10.0/24 [this gets changed to .9.0 on the
  other box]
- NAT/BINAT translation: none
- Remote Network: 192.168.9.0/24 [this gets changed to .10.0 on the
  other box]

I tried disabling the firewall completely to see if that was the issue, but it had no effect.

Comment: Make sure the subnet mask on both ends is 255.255.255.0 so you can see the entire subnet at each end

Comment: it seems more like a firewall problem on clients that prevent connections from a different network than the firewall on pfsense. also, how do host routes look like ?

Comment: @John: Both Subnets are 255.255.255.0

Comment: @Danfossi: I've tried with the firewalls off also [disabled from advanced settings]
When you say host routes, do you mean static routes?

Comment: yes, among the static routes there should be a gateway (usually ipsec server) that allows you to reach the remote network. regarding the firewall I had a similar problem even with the firewall disabled, I solved only by adding the remote network among the exceptions of the firewall, for this I was asking you to check the firewall.

Comment: @Danfossi I can't assign an interface in the Static Routes, i only get the gateways
System > Routing > Static Routes.

In Firewall > Rules > Interface
I have added  rule to allow all traffic from the remote LAN address.
Should I also add a rule to allow all traffic from the remote WAN address as well?

Comment: I am attaching the official netgate routing setup procedure: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/vpn/ipsec/routing-internet-traffic-through-a-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn.html 
(follow only: "allow-ipsec-traffic-through-the-firewall" section) and make sure you have created the rule as described. if you prefer the routed configuration (static route) you should follow these steps instead: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/vpn/ipsec/ipsec-routed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is sorted,

I had setup the IPsec firewall rules to go though the gateway on which IPsec was configured.

Once I changed the gateway settings to Default, it worked [almost] perfectly.

Now I can access some remote hosts, but not all.